# Using a sliding window with GLCM

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction, glcm

I'm trying to calculate various image features from the Gray-Level Co-occurence Matrix (GLCM) in MatLab using the `graycomatrix` function.

#### Example using graycomatrix

```
I = [0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 2 2 2; 2 2 3 3];
glcm = graycomatrix(I, 'GrayLimits', [0 3], 'NumLevels', 4, 'Symmetric', true);
```

How can I apply this function to a series of sub-windows assuming a larger image (640x480 for example) than the trivial example and a sliding window size of 5x5?

Comment: Please provide some more information than: please help I don't know how. Did you read the discription and the help files in the link at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22354-glcm-features4-m--vectorized-version-of-glcm-features1-m--with-code-changes-/content/GLCM_Features1.m?

Comment: yes I've read this article ,I want to apply this function on each moving window of image for all of pixels.

Comment: I have an 319x453  image that i want to extract GLCM featuresfrom this  ,my sub-window is [5 5] ,it's a moving window that move pixel by pixel and calculate these features for each window that is 2 neighborhood of everey pixel and these features will be collect for each pixel

Comment: @EJG89 I've improved the question to address some people's desire to close it. Could you please vote to reopen? I would like to answer this question without starting a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure a filtering approach is possible. I think you mean sth like this (let im be your grayscale image):

```
for ii=3:size(im,1)-2
    for jj=3:size(im,2)-2  % a loop for every pixel that a 5x5 window can be defined
        temp_im=im(ii-2:ii+2,jj-2:jj+2);  % crop a small window around pixel
        glcm=graycomatrix(temp_im);  % default parameters
        glcm_feat_struct=graycoprops(glcm);
        % extract features from struct and do anything you want
    end
end
```

Comment: Can I use the nlfilter function?

Comment: In your case nlfilter cannot be used, because the inner function must return a scalar. Have a look at [blockproc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html). Not having used it, I cannot provide an example, but it seems to be the most appropriate choice.

Comment: How can i save the feature vector for each pixel by these loop?

Comment: Let's say your image is M by N pixels and you want to extract 4 features, as provided by graycoprops (Contrast etc). Then, you can store the features for every pixel in a matrix, let's say:
'feat=zeros(M,N,4); % create it before the double loop'
and then, replace the comment inside the loop "extract features..." with:
'feat(ii,jj,1)=glcm_feat_struct.Contrast;'
'feat(ii,jj,2)=glcm_feat_struct.Correlation;'
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using nlfilter

I found this particular formulation and experimented with it. It has some limitations, but it isn't a terrible starting point.

```
function [ s ] = glcm_contrast(NHOOD)
%GLCM_CONTRAST
    glcm = graycomatrix(NHOOD, 'Offset', [0 1], 'GrayLimits', [0 3], 'NumLevels', 4, 'Symmetric', true);
    stats = graycoprops(glcm, 'contrast');
    s = stats.Contrast;
end

window_size = 5;
I = imread('yourImage.tif');
glcmfunc = @(x) glcm_contrast(x);
gray_limits = [min(I(:)), max(I(:))];
B = nlfilter(I, [window_size, window_size], glcmfunc);
```

#### Custom Matlab code

You might also want to take a look at my implementation of [Sliding GLCM](https://github.com/palmerc/GLCM) and see if you might want to expand upon that.